# reconfig Mongo replicaset increments version randomly

Tags: mongodb

When I reconfigure Mongo replicasets, I end up with a randomly incremented version number for the replset.  Everything works, but I'm worried the number may eventually overflow, since it seems to be incrementing geometrically.

If I do:

```
conf = rs.conf()
```

and check I will see `conf['version' ] = 1`
Then I do:

```
conf['members'][0]['priority'] = 2
rs.reconfig(conf, {force:1})
```

and it works, my replset has been reconfigured, but when I do:

```
conf = rs.conf()
```

`conf['version']` is something like `24956`.  And if I do it again, it becomes `83584` and then `282961`, etc. (it's not always those exact numbers, but the pattern is the same, random large increments, often doubling or worse).

This happens even if I specify the version number like this:

```
conf['members'][0]['priority'] = 2
conf['version'] = conf['version'] + 1
rs.reconfig(conf, {force:1})
```

Does anyone know what is going on with the underlying Mongo, and how I can get it to have reliable version number increments?  (I'm running Mongo 2.0.2 on Ubuntu).

BTW, this happens if I do it through the Mongo shell or using Pymongo `conn.admin.command('replSetReconfig', config)` to do it with a Python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The large random increment is how the force flag is implemented.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/repl/rs_config.cpp#L653:

```
void ReplSetConfig::init(BSONObj cfg, bool force) {
    _constructed = false;
    clear();
    from(cfg);
    if( force ) {
        version += rand() % 100000 + 10000;
    }
    configAssert( version < 0 /*unspecified*/ || (version >= 1) );
    if( version < 1 )
        version = 1;
    _ok = true;
    _constructed = true;
}
```

The replica set always uses the configuration with the highest version.  If you've already got the highest version, force is not required.  The large leap is trying to ensure that the new configuration is always the highest version even if another member of the set has a newer version than the one being updated.